# Delete Login/Crash History on Mac OS Yosemite

Tags: terminal, macos, console

I have an older iMac running Yosemite and I'm trying to delete the most recent login and crash history. When I type last and my username I see a bunch of crash reports but no option to delete them in Terminal.

Comment: The system cleans that file periodically as it fills. Is there a problem with seeing very small logs?

Comment: How long do they stay saved? I thought it keeps the login history and crash data forever... I notice when I open Terminal it has a line above my username that says restored?

Comment: Just type `last` and it will tell you the start date of your current history.

Comment: Yes I did that. How do I start fresh?

Comment: Can you show some sample output from `last` you are concerned about, especially the crash history it shows?

Comment: Is there no way to safely (without harm) clear the login history for the past month? How long does Yosemite keep the login history for? Thanks